# jQuery and Selenium IDE - how to select a specific tr that contains td's with?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium-ide

Please,I wonder how I can capture more than one td value in a tr with Jquery to Selenium IDE

the code is similar:

```
<tr>
  <td>ACE TEST</td>
  <td>Cash</td>
  <td>100,00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ACE TEST</td>
   <td>Credit</td>
   <td>100,00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>EVALY TEST</td>
  <td>Cash</td>
  <td>100,00</td>
</tr>
```

in this case .. the only one that differs is the type of payment (Cash x Credit). I tried
the code Selenium IDE, but serves only to a value :

```
runScript |
jQuery('tr:contains("ACE TEST"):first .icon-edit').click()</td>
```

Comment: for example:

... tr:contains("ACE TEST" , "Cash"):first .icon-edit').click()...

How to make a selection like this?

Comment: I got it.. thanks for listening!!!  
runScript |
jQuery('tr:contains("ACE TEST"):contains("Cash")').find('.icon-edit').click()

Comment: You can also avoid using jquery entirely and only selenium ide. Use click command with this xpath that finds the row containing the correct td elements. `//td[contains(text(), 'ACE TEST')]/following-sibling::td[contains(text(), 'Cash')]/following-sibling::td[contains(text(), '100,00')]/ancestor::tr`